# Same Form, different behaviour

Tags: php, html, forms

So I am using the exact same contact form on two different websites but they act very differently. In the one website, the success/error message loads on the same page (it replaces   the  of the form and applies the css to make it look nice. On the second website, it opens a new window, no css is applied. I cannot figure out why two forms, exactly the same, act so differently. I have not applied any css to the form on the second site that opens in a new window but do not think that should be causing any major issues.

I have tried hard-coding a target=_self command, replacing the entire code blocks and numerous other hacks/fixes but nothing solves the problem.

The forms HTML:

```
    <fieldset>
                <div id="form_wrapper">
                <div id="form_left">
                <p><label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required"></span>    </label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name"/>    </p>
                <p><label for="email" accesskey="E"><span class="required"></span>    </label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value=""  placeholder="Email"/></p>
                <p><label for="phone" accesskey="P"><span class="optional"></span>    </label>
                <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" value=""  placeholder="Phone (optional)"/></p>
                </div>

                <div id="form_right">
                <p><label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required"></span></label>
                <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Type message here..."></textarea></p> 

                <div id="spam">
                <div id="spam_2">
                <label for="verify" accesskey="V"><img src="/image.php" alt="" /></label>
                <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" placeholder="Enter Characters"/></div>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
```

The form.php in the action (I have removed an if statement that checks spam validation, check the last code block):

```
<?php session_start();

if(!$_POST) exit;

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Simple Configuration Options

// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

$address = "bbanger@websitesandseo.co.za";

// Twitter Direct Message notification control.
    // Set $twitter_active to 0 to disable Twitter Notification
    $twitter_active     = 0;

    // Get your consumer key and consumer secret from http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
        // Notes:
            // Application Name: Jigowatt Contact Form
            // Description: Jigowatt Contact Form Direct Messaging Funcionality
            // Application Website: (your website address)
            // Application Type: Browser
            // Callback URL: (Blank)
            // Default Access type: Read and Write
    $twitter_user       = ""; // Your user name
    $consumer_key       = "";
    $consumer_secret    = "";

    // Access Token and Access Token Secret is under "My Access Token" (right menu).
    $token              = "";
    $secret             = "";

// END OF Simple Configuration Options

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Only edit below this line if either instructed to do so by the author or have extensive PHP knowledge.
// Please Note, we cannot support this file package if modifications have been made below this line.

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if (isset($_POST['verify'])) :
    $posted_verify   = $_POST['verify'];
    $posted_verify   = md5($posted_verify);
else :
    $posted_verify = '';
endif;

// Important Variables
$session_verify = $_SESSION['verify'];

if (empty($session_verify)) $session_verify = $_COOKIE['verify'];

$error = '';

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your name is required.</li>';
    }

    if(trim($email) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your e-mail address is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!isEmail($email)) {
        $error .= '<li>You have entered an invalid e-mail address.</li>';
    }


    if(trim($comments) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>You must enter a message to send.</li>';
    }


    if($error != '') { 
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please correct the errors below and try again.';
        echo '<ul class="error_messages">' . $error . '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';

    } else {

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comments = stripslashes($comments); }

     // Advanced Configuration Option.
     // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

     $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';

     // Advanced Configuration Option.
     // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
     // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

     $msg  = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, they passed verification and their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "This message was sent to you via the Energy Amplified Website Contact Form";

    if($twitter_active == 1) { 

        $twitter_msg = $name . " - " . $comments . ". You can contact " . $name . " via email, " . $email ." or via phone " . $phone . ".";
        twittermessage($twitter_user, $twitter_msg, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $secret);

    }

    $msg = wordwrap( $msg, 70 );

    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

     echo "<fieldset>";         
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</fieldset>";

     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!'; // Dont Edit.

     }

}

function twittermessage($user, $message, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $secret) { // Twitter Direct Message function, do not edit.

require_once('twitter/EpiCurl.php');
require_once('twitter/EpiOAuth.php');
require_once('twitter/EpiTwitter.php');

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$Twitter->setToken($token, $secret);

$direct_message = $Twitter->post_direct_messagesNew( array('user' => $user, 'text' => $message) );
$tweet_info = $direct_message->responseText;

}

function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));

}
?>
```

The pieces I removed between the two pages:

```
    if(trim($phone) == '') {
        $error .= '<li>Your phone number is required.</li>';
    } elseif(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        $error .= '<li>Your phone number can only contain digits.</li>';
    }



    if($session_verify != $posted_verify) {
        $error .= '<li>The verification code you entered is incorrect.</li>';
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean, opens a new window? Can you share links?

Comment: The first is www websitesandseo co za - you will need to use the form on the contact page. The second is www energyamplified co za - click on the contact link in the menu - it is this second site that launches a new window.Sorry I am writing the URL's based but Google keeps on indexing these posts. The domain is .co.za. Thank you.

Comment: First site seems like using ajax. Thats why it opens in same page.

Comment: Hi Kuzgun. I dont see anything Ajax on the page or in the form that would differentiate the one as using Ajax and the other as not - can you please clarify? –  Byron

Comment: http://www.websitesandseo.co.za/js/jquery.jigowatt.js

Comment: That was the missing link - thank you so much! Feel free to place that in the answer and I will give it a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kuzgun mention, I was missing a .js file on the domain